# Is it better to predict one continuous target or split it to set of N discrete bins in DNN training?

Tags: neural-networks, continuous-data, discrete-data

I am going to train a DNN to predict a continuous target $Y$ that can reach values $<0,60>$. In a research I have read, such interval was split into a set of $N$ discrete values $Y_1,...Y_N$. I know this way you miss some possible information, lets say that if the interval is cut by 5, the error can be 2.5.

My question is, what is the benefit of discretization here? Will the DNN learn faster or become more accurate than with single continuous target?

Comment: It *cannot* be more accurate because if you make it a classification problem it will produce only N possible values vs continuous values. Where exactly did you read that this is a good idea?

Comment: @Tim I am analysing [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9369397), especially the z coordinate prediction (section IV.B).

Comment: @Tim it can and often is more accurate. This has been done, notably, in Kaggle in the past. About the question, it is impossible to answer a priori, due to no free lunch theorem. Think about the loss functions, compare it with MSE and see how errors are differently penalized under these two losses.

Comment: @Firebug with binning the upper bound for accuracy is limited by rounding errors due to binning. With continuous response the upper bound is perfect accuracy. Sure, good binned model might be better than poor regression one, but you shouldn’t prefer it without a very good reason to do so.

Comment: @Tim Kaggle is empirical. It worked in that past competition (can't remember which one it was). This is usually called regression by classification, or regression as classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what is the benefit of discretization here?

There is no benefit.  Doing so can result in large residual confounding; there could be additional variation you could explain had you just left the outcome as continuous.  This can lead to poorer prediction systematically.

Here is an example.  I'm going to generate some data according to

$$ y = \log(x) + \epsilon $$

Here $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$. The output is a continuous quantity, but let's instead bin the output into buckets of width 2.  Here is some R code to do that

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(VGAM)

generate_data<-function(n){
  
  x = runif(n,0, 10)
  y = log(x) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.5)
  d = tibble(x, y)
}

d = generate_data(1000) %>% 
  mutate(ybin = plyr::round_any(y, 2),
         ybin = factor(ybin, ordered = T))

dtest = generate_data(10000) %>% 
        mutate(ybin = plyr::round_any(y, 2),
              ybin = factor(ybin, ordered = T))
```

Since I've bucketed the outcome, it is an ordered categorical variable.  That means I can use something like a multinomial regression (though since groups are perfectly separable, I will get warnings about complete separation.   We can however persevere).  Let's fit the model and apply the model to our test data

```
model = vglm(ybin ~ x, data = d, family=multinomial())

preds = predict(model, newdata=dtest, type='response')
cats = colnames(preds)
dtest$predictions = as.numeric(cats[apply(preds, 1, which.max)])
```

We can even take a peek at the confusion matrix

```
> xtabs(~ybin+predictions, data = dtest)
     predictions
ybin     -4    -2     0     2
  -10     1     0     0     0
  -8     16     0     0     0
  -6     79     0     0     0
  -4    377   116     0     0
  -2    118  2683   840     0
  0       0   817 19479  6321
  2       0     0  5482 62063
  4       0     0     1  1607
```

Seems like this is OK.  The model has an accuracy of 84%, and an F1 score of 66%.  Not bad from a classification perspective, but remember this is a regression problem.  We should be evaluating the prediction's MSE.  Let's do that now

```r
Metrics::mse(dtest$y, dtest$predictions)
[1] 0.4892551
```

Not bad.  Now, let's fit a spline and see how just leaving the output as a continuous quantity would do

```
library(splines)
model2 = lm(y~bs(x, df=4), data = d)

dtest$spline_pred = predict(model2, newdata=dtest)
Metrics::mse(dtest$y, dtest$spline_pred)
[1] 0.2978704
```

Treating the output as continuous leads to better prediction error as evaluated by MSE.

There may be circumstances where this is a reasonable approach, but the preference is to analyze data as it is.  Binning the outcome is a very poor idea, and leads to loss of information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the answer seems correct but I am not sure, the DNN I seen had N output neurons. It seems that you have only binned it and used a single target containing bins. Maybe I am wrong, I am not very familiar with R. The authors of the publication have claimed you need significantly more data points for regression as for classification and the gain is not that great and that is their motivation. Might that be true?